# How to Fix Could not find browser revision 756035

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer

I am using `puppeteer` to execute some test cases in `Docker` and I get this below error:

> "before all" hook: codeceptjs.beforeSuite for "Validate_onbord_broker_business":
> Could not find browser revision 756035. Run "npm install" or "yarn install" to download a browser binary.
> at ChromeLauncher.launch (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:59:23)
> at async Puppeteer._startBrowser (node_modules/codeceptjs/lib/helper/Puppeteer.js:512:22)

And this is the `Dockerfile` I am using:

```
# Use whatever version you are running locally (see node -v)
FROM node:12.18

WORKDIR /app

RUN  apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y wget gnupg ca-certificates \
     && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
     && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
     && apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
     && wget --quiet https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh -O /usr/sbin/wait-for-it.sh \
     && chmod +x /usr/sbin/wait-for-it.sh

# Install dependencies (you are already in /app)
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
# RUN npm ci
RUN npm install
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
RUN npm install codeceptjs puppeteer
COPY . /app

RUN pwd
RUN ls


# RUN npx codeceptjs init


RUN npx codeceptjs run 

# CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Can someone please help me what is going wrong?

Comment: Is the version of Chrome you install with `apt-get` compatible with the version of Puppeteer you install with `npm install`? From the error, it looks like it is not. Just to confirm, try without the `PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD` env var and without separately installing Chrome and see if that helps!

Comment: I tried your way but I still get a different error as: `Failed to launch the browser process!
/home/runner/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-756035/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're skipping downloading a version of chromium when you install your dependencies: `ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true`. Puppeteer is only guaranteed to work with the bundled version of chromium and it's generally a bad idea to use some other version of chromium.

Based on your comments on your post, I'm *guessing* that the reason you're not using the bundled version of Chromium is because you're having "fun" with dependencies. These can be manually installed using `apt` - here are the dependencies which are installed by the [official puppeteer dockerfile](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/.ci/node12/Dockerfile.linux#L4):

```
apt-get -y install xvfb gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 \
      libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 \
      libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 \
      libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 \
      libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

I think this is the updated `Dockerfile` - let me know if it works because I can't test it without the rest of your code!

```
# Use whatever version you are running locally (see node -v)
FROM node:12.18

WORKDIR /app

RUN  apt-get update \
     && apt-get -y install xvfb gconf-service gnupg libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 \
      libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 \
      libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 \
      libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 \
      libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget \
     && wget --quiet https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh -O /usr/sbin/wait-for-it.sh \
     && chmod +x /usr/sbin/wait-for-it.sh

# Install dependencies (you are already in /app)
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
# RUN npm ci
RUN npm install
RUN npm install codeceptjs puppeteer
COPY . /app

RUN pwd
RUN ls


# RUN npx codeceptjs init


RUN npx codeceptjs run 

# CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: No, it is skipped because I am already installing chromium in the above command

Comment: D'oh! My bad, apologies. Have you pointed your code to the chrome binary that you downloaded using apt?

Comment: Yes, but I get this error now: `Could not find browser revision 756035. Run "npm install" or "yarn install" to download a browser binary.`

Comment: I think this problem stems from the fact that puppeteer is only guaranteed to work with the bundled version of chromium. I'll update my answer appropriately.

Comment: can you provide the complete `Dockerfile` with your changes?

Comment: Added updated Dockerfile as requested :-)